# How is it possible to debug LARAVEL 419 POST error?

Tags: php, ajax, angular, laravel, laravel-5

I would like to send a CORS post request to my Laravel app. Unfortunately I get a 419 error with an empty error message, and I have no idea how to debug it.

I've found many questions with this error, and the solution is usually to add an `X-CSRF-Token` to the request. I already send this header, and I still get the error. How is it possible to find out, why I get the error?

I web middleware and `barryvdh/laravel-cors` to enable cross origin requests.

---

The response is this:

```
{
    "message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException",
    "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php",
    "line": 204,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php",
            "line": 176,
            "function": "prepareException",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\app\\Exceptions\\Handler.php",
            "line": 49,
            "function": "render",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 83,
            "function": "render",
            "class": "App\\Exceptions\\Handler",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 55,
            "function": "handleException",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession.php",
            "line": 49,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php",
            "line": 56,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php",
            "line": 37,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php",
            "line": 66,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 104,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 682,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 657,
            "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 623,
            "function": "runRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 612,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 176,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 30,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\barryvdh\\laravel-cors\\src\\HandleCors.php",
            "line": 58,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Barryvdh\\Cors\\HandleCors",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 57,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
            "line": 62,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 104,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 151,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 116,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\public\\index.php",
            "line": 55,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\server.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "require_once"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you using the `api` middleware group?

Comment: Can you post the content of your log file?

Comment: I use the web middleware. I updated the question with the error log

Comment: Where are you getting the token from that you pass in `X-CSRF-Token`? I suspect it's an invalid token.

Answer (score 0):

This appears in your errors.

`{
            "file": "D:\\projects\\MyApp\\vendor\\barryvdh\\laravel-cors\\src\\HandleCors.php",
            "line": 58,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        }`

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors/blob/c95ac944f2f20a17949aae6645692dfd3b402bca/src/HandleCors.php#L58

You've made it past CORS.  How's the CSRF situation?